# Cloudflare Workers - selectively cache HTML content

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I'm wanting to create a Cloudflare Worker which selectively caches HTML page contents equivalent to if I had a page rule for cache-level=cache everything, edge cache TTL=30 mins

Requests going via the below, simplified, worker code never hit the cache, instead making a request from my origin every time. 
Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)

  if (request.method == "GET" && url.pathname == "/foo/bar") {
    newurl=url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname + url.pathname + "?" + url.search
    let response = await fetch(newurl, request, { cf: { cacheTtl: 1800 } })
    response = new Response(response.body, response)
    response.headers.delete("pragma")
    return response
  } else {
    const response = await fetch(request) 
    return response 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call is the problem:

```
fetch(newurl, request, { cf: { cacheTtl: 1800 } })
```

`fetch()` takes two parameters, not three. JavaScript calling convention ignores extra parameters, so your `{ cf: { cacheTtl: 1800 } }` is being ignored.

It looks like you aren't actually making changes to the URL, so perhaps you could simply do:

```
fetch(request, { cf: { cacheTtl: 1800 } })
```

If you really do want to rewrite the URL, then you'll need a two-step process:

```
request = new Request(newurl, request);
let response = await fetch(request, { cf: { cacheTtl: 1800 } });
```

Comment: Thanks, splitting it into the 2 lines worked. In the real code I do change the url, I omitted that to simplify the example.